# Test-NetConnection behaves differently in one specific port

Tags: powershell, enumeration

I'm currently finishing the Try Hack Me's "Hacking with Powershell" room. In the last challenge, you are supposed to write a script to find all open ports within a range [130-140]. Here is my attempt at that (Note the fourth line is just for debugging):

```
$n = 0
for($i=130; $i -le 140; $i++){
    $res = Test-NetConnection localhost -port $i -InformationLevel Detailed
    echo $res
    if($res.PingSucceeded -eq "True"){
        $n++
    }
}

echo $n
```

The output from the echo $res command show the following for all ports exept for 135:

[image: Non 135 port scan]

But for port 135 the "PingSucceeded" property doesn't show:
[image: Port 135 scan]

The script outputs 10 open ports (all except 135), but THM's stated correct answer is 11.

Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: are you sure you dont want `if($res.TcpTestSucceeded) {` instead of `if($res.PingSucceeded -eq "True") {` also note `"True"` is just a string, not a boolean (`$true`)

Comment: What about `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort (130..140)`?

Comment: With TcpTestSucceeded I get only one port listening... That may be the answer because thats what I get with netstat and with Get-NetTCPConnection I get 2, as @stackprotector suggests. I've written to THM to ask if the answer is correct. Nonetheless I'm still puzzled by the difference in the outputs.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon also thanks for the code improvement.

Comment: `PingSucceeded` simply means the remote host responded to a ICMP request. If you're interested in TCP you should always look into the `TcpTestSucceeded` property

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers I got, I've realized I was confusing PingSucceeded with the port being open. So in my script I was actually looking for $res.TcpTestSucceeded.

It seems that on listening ports (135 on this case, but can also replicate on 445, 3389, 5985) the property PingSucceeded and PingReplyDetails (RTT) doesn't appear. If anyone else has info on this I'd appreciate it, else I'm selecting this as the accepted answer.